# Why does "View page source" differ from "Inspect" on some websites and how can I download what I see in Inspect?

Tags: html

I am trying to download the webpage but the file differs in what I download, the page source, and the inspection. How can I download what is shown in the Inspection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`View page source` returns the **static html page as sent by the server and loaded by the browser**.

While `inspect` will show **the current state of the DOM and any dynamic elements that might have been added by javascript that runs in the page**.

To download what you see in inspection you will need a headless browser (eg [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/)) which can run javascript as well instead of simply downloading the static html page and then hook into the headless browser and get the DOM as text.

Comment: What if I need to scroll down to load more items? Do headless browsers support that?

Comment: phantom.js is scriptable and supports various DOM manipulations I think it can support this but better check the documentation